# how open IDEA 11 new window in current window

Tags: intellij-idea

i'm using macbook pro.

idea 10 can open more than one window , but 11 cannot, do u can ?

Does Setting contains the conf?

switch window is command+~ key, or F10.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable the **Confirm window to open project in** option:

[image: confirm]

Comment: Wow. That's one hilariously titled option. I know I'd never find it with that description. Neat yellow box and everything. :)